# how can i get a shipping cost of ordered items in an e-commerce website

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, e-commerce

i am working on an e-commerce website with django and i want to include the shipping cost in the checkout page. is there a way to calculate the shipping cost with django or javascript?

Comment: There is no universal way to calculate the shipping cost: it will depend from the vector, the destination, the parcel size and weight, the type of delivery, etc... Usually vectors provide APIs which will return the shipping cost, given the various options so you send the delivery data and the API gives you back the cost, ready to be added to the invoice.

Comment: Thank you for answering which api do you recommend?

Comment: the vector depends on the country of origin and the postal services in said country

Comment: @NahuGere, it is not an issue of recommendation; it depends on which vector your e-commerce uses: if you send via DHL, you will have to look for DHL API, if you send via FedEx you will have to use FedEx API, etc. That is a commercial decision, not a development one.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question